# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string (Laravel 5.7.1)

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to send mail by template from contact page. Mail sent successfully but when I'm trying to show the user given message then it shows a problem as bellow:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\laragon\www\square_chili\resources\views\partials\email\contactEmail.blade.php)
```

Now, how could I solve this problem..??

contactEmail.blade.php:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="subject">
        <h4>Subject</h4>
        <div class="subject-div">
            <h3>{{ $subject }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <div class="name-div">
            <h3>{{ $name }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <h4>Email Address</h4>
        <div class="email-div">
            <h3>{{ $email }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <h4>Message</h4>
        <div class="message-div">
            <h6>{{ $message }}</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ContactController (store):

```
$mailData = [
    'name' => $request - > first_name.
    " ".$request - > last_name,
    'email' => $request - > email,
    'subject' => $request - > subject,
    'message' => $request - > message
];

Mail::send('partials.email.contactEmail', $mailData, function($message) use($mailData) {
    $message - > to($mailData['email']);
    $message - > subject($mailData['subject']);
    $message - > from('mymail@gmail.com');
});
```

Comment: There's no `htmlspecialchars` in the code. Use xdebug to backtrace call stacks.

Comment: Which line is the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just Change the variable name 'message'

`'msg' => $request->message`

Comment: What's the explanation for his solution?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir It's because "message" is a reserved variable in Laravel mail's internal class. You can't use this as your variable name.

Answer (score 2):

On your Contact controller remove the space from the object operators `->`.

Try this

```
$mailData = [
  'name' => $request->first_name." ".$request->last_name,
  'email' => $request->email,
  'subject' => $request->subject,
  'message' => $request->message
];
```

Comment: I'm even wondering about the error message, should be *syntax error, unexpected '>'*. There might be something wrong with the question at all.

Comment: If I just removing this codes from my view file it successfully sending message.
`<div class="message">
        <h4>Message</h4>
        <div class="message-div">
            <h6>{{ $message }}</h6>
        </div>
    </div>`
But It can't get the value of $message variable.